# find_under_expand_skip command for Sublime Text not working

Tags: sublimetext

The `find_under_expand_skip` is not working. I've used the command before on a different machine, so I'm certain that I'm typing the hotkey sequence (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>) correctly. I'm on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the hotkey sequence (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>) was being used by the **Diffy** package. Removing the **Diffy** package fixed the problem:

1. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
2. type `Package Control: Remove Package` then press <kbd>enter</kbd>
3. type `Diffy` then press <kbd>enter</kbd>
4. done!

Comment: If you like the `Diffy` package otherwise, you can copy the default binding for this to your user bindings to stop `Diffy` from stealing the binding. Key bindings in your `User` package always have the final say.